# Display an infinity sign within a table cell

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I used [this website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) to generate a table, of which some cells contain an infinity sign.
As cells are filled with text, the website automatically inserted `\textbackslash{}infty` in the cells. However, LaTeX prints this cell as text, namely "\infty".

If, however, I insert `\infty` into the cells, this error message occurs:

```
! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>$ ...
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: why use a generator? especially if it generates over complicated or incorrect code, but `$\infty$`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `\infty` is recognized as a math symbol, and indication in input that it is math is required.  Wrap it in `$` signs: `$\infty$`.

Comment: if  your table is mostly math you can use `array` instead of `tabular`, they are identical except array sets cells in math mode so you do not need `$`

Comment: Thank you for your replies! It works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace all instances of

```
\textbackslash{}infty
```

with

```
$\infty$
```

The `$` symbols serve to initiate and terminate TeX's inline math mode. Their presence is necessary as the macro `\infty` expects to be processed in math mode, not text mode.